# Assign numeric results from query to text from array

Tags: php

I'm just learning PHP and I've searched for a while on this, but I'm afraid I may not know exactly how to ask it, so an explanation will probably work best.  Basically I have a group by/count query returning 3 records.

```
Status    Total
  0         2
  1         3
  2         2
```

On my page I would like to display:

```
Status          Total
 Dev             2
 Active          3
 Arch            2
```

So I basically just want to assign the values 0, 1 and 2 to a text value.  I've tried creating an array, then assigning the return number field equal to the array.

```
$_status = array(0 => 'Development', 1 => 'Production', 2 => 'Archive');

while($rowStat = mysql_fetch_assoc($resDev))
{
    echo "<tr><td>$_status[$rowStat['status']]</td><td>{$rowStat['devprojects']}</td></tr>";
};
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In development you should turn error reporting up to `E_ALL`.  This would have told you that the key `status` didn't exist (since it's actually `Status` with a capital S).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really like using the 0, 1, 2 to represent a named value (unless you have a relational) table in your DB... but using your setup, why not just use:

```
while($rowStat = mysql_fetch_assoc($resDev)){
    switch($rowStat['Status']){
        case 0:
            echo "<tr><td>Development</td><td>{$rowStat['devprojects']}</td></tr>";
        break;
        case 1:
            echo "<tr><td>Production</td><td>{$rowStat['devprojects']}</td></tr>";
        break;
        case 2:
            echo "<tr><td>Archive</td><td>{$rowStat['devprojects']}</td></tr>";
        break;
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

Some people really are looking for copy-paste answers so here's an updated answer because Sgt. Crashspeeder of the Massively Anal Society got her knickers in a twist.

Create a lookup array to reference against the status Ids:

```
$statusArray[0] = 'Development;
$statusArray[1] = 'Production;
$statusArray[2] = 'Archive;
```

Then when you're running your mysql_fetch_assoc() loop, you can reference the statusArray lookup like so:

```
while($rowStat = mysql_fetch_assoc($resDev)){
    echo "<tr><td>{$statusArray[$rowStat['Status']]}</td><td>{$rowStat['devprojects']}</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Too much repetition of code.  If the only thing changing is what's in the first column of the row there's no reason to reprint the whole thing.  Additionally, you didn't fix the error, which was the lowercase `S` in `status`.  It should be `Status` with a capital S.  Your code still wouldn't work.

Comment: This worked.  I should have specified, in the table the status field is called "status" (all lowercase).  In my example where I had "Status", thats what I was specifying in my table view on my page.  Is there a way to do this array, too?

Comment: the "$_status" is the array I was trying to create to assign the values from the variable in my table.

Comment: Updated my answer because Sgt. Crashspeeder said so.

Answer (score 1):

as you can see here http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc the field names are case sensitive

from what I see in your table sample the field is called "Status"

and you are using "status"

you can try changing

```
$rowStat['status']
```

to

```
$rowStat['Status']
```

Edit:

the initial version of the answer only focused on what's the problem (and suggested pdo)
I only want to add that I agree to two other optinions found here:
the one added via comment to this answer by giorgio: you should only use lowercase names for your database fields; also you should consider using the table name as a prefix (product_id instead or id, user_password instead of password) for two main reasons: to avoid colisions when you fetch results using a join and to avoit collisions with mysql reserved words (as id, password and status are)

the other one, suggested by Crashspeeder by a comment to the question: you definitely should develop with error reporting on and disable it on live servers

Comment: you might want to change the field names to lowercase. By convention variables and sql column/table/database names are written in lowercase. Exceptions are; class variables ($camelCase) and php variables with more than one word ($seperated_by_underscore).

Comment: @giorgio very good addition.. one thing.. php variables separated using underscore doesn't seem like an exception :) database fields should have more than one word also and underscores (in my opinion) are the best way to separate them

Comment: lol :p you're perfectly right, that was more an addition than an exception, but well, i guess op gets what i mean ;) And yes, i agree, mulitple-word column/database field names should be separated by underscore too!